# Rails - consultar por registros não correspondentes

Tags: sql, query, ruby-on-rails

Eu tenho uma aplicação Rails e estou criando um sistema de notificações, o problema é que eu não sei como consultar pelas notificações não visualizadas por um usuário de maneira prática.

O esquema da tabela de notificações é o seguinte:

```
create_table "notifications", force: :cascade do |t|t.integer  "performer_id"
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "kind"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.index ["performer_id"], name: "index_notifications_on_performer_id"
end
```

O da tabela de visualizações é:

```
create_table "visualizations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "notification_id",                 null: false
    t.integer "collaborator_id",                 null: false
    t.boolean "visualized",      default: false
    t.index ["collaborator_id"], name: "index_visualizations_on_collaborator_id"
    t.index ["notification_id"], name: "index_visualizations_on_notification_id"
end
```

Claro, eu tenho os modelos `Notification` e `Visualization` na aplicação.

Que consulta eu poderia fazer para selecionar todas as notificações para um usuário da qual não exista um registro de visualização na tabela de visualizações?

Pergunto isso porque não tenho muita experiência em SQL pra pensar numa consulta e também sou o único desenvolvedor da aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Para deixar um pouco mais "Rails", performática e que evita qualquer tipo de SQL injection, te dou uma alternativa à [resposta do @Danilo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308052/41056).

```
user = User.first
user.notifications
  .left_outer_joins(:visualizations)
  .where(visualizations: { id: nil })
```

Isso vai funcionar para o Rails 5, onde o `left_outer_joins` foi adicionado. Hoje, é a forma mais performática e idiomática de fazer.

O problema com o `includes` é que vai forçar o um *eager load*, carregando para cada notificação, suas respectivas visualizações. Com o `left_outer_joins`, você evita todo o carregamento feito, só pegando o que é realmente necessário.

Uma outra dica: para respeitar o [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), pode colocar no model `Notification`, um [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  scope :only_unseen, -> { left_outer_joins(:visualizations).where(visualizations: { id: nil }) }
end
```

Assim, sempre que quiser as notificações não visualizadas, pode fazer:

```
Notification.only_unseen
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dê uma lida em Active Record Query Interface

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

## Associações

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations

---

O rails tem uma forma de pesquisar que você não precisa usar SQL. *Só quando realmente precisa.*

```
id_colaborador = 123

Notification.includes(:visualizations)
 .where("visualizations.collaborator_id = ? and visualizations.visualized = false", id_colaborador)
```